# Using PIPE in long subprocess call (python) doesn't work

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, popen, sudo

I am trying to do the following command (to download Calibre through a python script):

sudo -v && wget -nv -O- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kovidgoyal/calibre/master/setup/linux-installer.py | sudo python -c "import sys; main=lambda:sys.stderr.write('Download failed\n'); exec(sys.stdin.read()); main()"

Following some of the answers on here on how to PIPE, I have been doing this:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
wget = subprocess.Popen(["sudo -v wget -nv -O- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kovidgoyal/calibre/master/setup/linux-installer.py"], stdout=PIPE) 
run = subprocess.Popen(["sudo python -c "import sys; exec(sys.stdin.read()); main()""], stdin=wget.stdout)
```

I have tried changing many things but NOTHING is working. There are too many errors to put here. Can anyone correct this? Many thanks in advance.

All I get is the first

Comment: -1. "NOTHING is working" -- the code in your question doesn't show much effort e.g., it contains `SyntaxError`s (quotes usage). You should fix them *before* posting a question. The `Popen()` usage in your code is also incorrect: at the very least you should read the description of the first parameter `args` that specifies the command to run. Is the phrase ["a sequence of program arguments"](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) not sufficiently clear? Why do you call `Popen(["cmd arg1 arg2"])` instead of `Popen(["cmd", "arg1", "arg2"])`?

Comment: It may not show effort, but saying "I have tried changing many things" is better than showing you all a HUGE message describing every little error I get on each slight alteration of the code. If you want, I can email you the whole list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have parameters you need to break it into a list, e.g.

```
wget = subprocess.Popen(["wget -nv -O- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kovidgoyal/calibre/master/setup/linux-installer.py"]) 

(**No such file or directory** error, because it looks for that whole string as a command/file)
```

Needs to become:

```
subprocess.Popen(['wget', '-nv', '-O-', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kovidgoyal/calibre/master/setup/linux-installer.py'])
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x10e203950>
```

You can also use `shlex.split()` to split your command for you, e.g.

```
>>> import shlex
>>> shlex.split('wget -nv -O- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kovidgoyal/calibre/master/setup/linux-installer.py')
['wget', '-nv', '-O-', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kovidgoyal/calibre/master/setup/linux-installer.py']
```

Ref. https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor

You also have `"sudo python -c "import sys; exec(sys.stdin.read()); main()""`, I don't think it's acceptable syntax because you have quotes inside quotes (the inside ones close out the first opening quote), so try `'sudo python -c "import sys; exec(sys.stdin.read()); main()"'` with single quotes instead, that way you don't have to escape the quotes inside!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid escaping quotes inside the command, you could use triple quotes:

```
from subprocess import check_call

check_call(r'''# http://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux
  sudo -v &&
  wget -nv -O- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kovidgoyal/calibre/master/setup/linux-installer.py |
  sudo python -c "import sys; main=lambda:sys.stderr.write('Download failed\n'); exec(sys.stdin.read()); main()"
''', shell=True)
```

`shell=True` causes the first parameter to be interpreted as a shell command.

In principle, you could simplify the command:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import sys
from subprocess import check_call
from urllib.request import urlretrieve

# http://calibre-ebook.com/download_linux
path, _ = urlretrieve('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kovidgoyal/calibre/master/setup/linux-installer.py')
check_call(['sudo', sys.executable, path])
```

but it may have subtle security implications e.g., `urlretrieve()` may skip server ssl certificate validation.